# mitmproxy reset an option (view_filter)?

Tags: mitmproxy

I have a ~/.mitmproxy/keys.yaml hotkey config file for mitmproxy and a part of the file is as follows.

```
-
    key: ctrl f
    cmd: set view_filter '!(~t "text/html" | ~t "text/css" | ~t "image/" | ~t "/javascript")'
-
    key: ctrl i
    cmd: set view_filter ''
```

So I use often a long view_filter command so I added it to the file, as specified on "ctrl f" above.

When I hit ctrl-f I can get the filter onto the mitmproxy viewer instantly, that's great, but usually I want to revert that filter back to the default empty one.

So I added `set view_filter ''` command with the "ctrl i" hotkey on the file as above. But It didn't work as expected, when I hit ctrl-i, it does nothing, no error on the log.

So how can I make/reset a option (view_filter) default?